# iOS: Is there a way to set programmatically all the fonts of the storyboard in a specific font?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel, uistoryboard

I would like to know if there is an easy way to change the font of all labels, textviews, buttons, talbeviewcells, etc... in a StoryBoard programmatically, without adding them in the viewcontroller?

I do it manually for now, but I wonder if an easy solution exists?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in code
Swift

```
 UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
```

UPDATE:
Obj-c (without changing the size): 
Put at the beginning:

```
@implementation UILabel(SizedFontName)
- (void)setSizedFontName:(NSString *)name UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR
{
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:self.font.pointSize];
}
@end
```

In the viewDidLoad:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setSizedFontName:@"RenaultLife"];
```